# Adding a Password Recovery option to WSO2 sign-in

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I was wondering if there is an option for users who want to use the store but have forgotten their password

Currently the WSO2 sign-in page looks like this:
[image: WSO2 Sign-in page, requires a password recovery option]

I have set the following in < APIM_HOME >/repository/conf/identity/identity­-mgt.properties:

> Identity.Listener.Enable=true 
>   Notification.Sending.Enable=true 
>   Notification.Expire.Time=3 
>   Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true 
>   UserAccount.Recovery.Enable=true 
>   Captcha.Verification.Internally.Managed=true

I'm assuming the email settings for the same are in < APIM_HOME >/repository/conf/email/email-admin-config.xml

Anyhow, after applying the above settings and restarting the server, the sign-in page remained the same.

Is there some configuration to enable an option on the sign-in page (eg. Forgot password/Reset password)?
Also, are there any additional settings that need to be configured for it to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

API Manager Store/Publisher UIs do not support this out-of-the-box. But you can achieve this with WSO2 Identity server. (You can use the same [identity server, as key manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0) node of the APIM setup)

Please refer to [IS docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Password+Recovery). A sample webapp also available [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/v5.2.0/modules/samples/identity-mgt).

Comment: How to use this without using IS. Is there any way to install required features in API manager & start using password recovery. Its really difficult to install one server for only password recovery.

Comment: Yes, you can install identity-management features to APIM. Steps are similar to this. https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0

Comment: I tried to install this features in api manager but getting some errors while install. I am using API manager 2.0.

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Account Recovery and Credential Management Feature 5.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.feature.group 5.2.2) Software currently installed: Identity Core Feature 5.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.feature.group 5.2.0) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Identity Core Server Feature 5.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.server.feature.jar 5.2.0)